# Getting the current month in a timezone in Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the current month number using the following simple code in a `Controller`:

```
@month = DateTime.now.month
```

In my `application_controller.rb`:

```
around_filter :use_time_zone

def use_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)', &block)
end
```

And it seems to work great. Though I did see some kind of Rails 4 deprecation warning somewhere, I think in my production logs. Maybe that's the cause of my issue?

What happens is when I deploy to Heroku, the `@month` I'm guessing is using UTC time instead of Pacific. It's 5:30pm March 31 right now and `@month` is 4 (April). But only in production on Heroku, locally (using SQLite3 if that matters), @month is correctly 3 (March).

How do I get the correct month for a particular timezone on Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)').month` or `DateTime.now.in_time_zone.month`.  In the latter case the time zone returned by `Time.zone` is used.

Unlike `Time.zone.now` and `DateTime.current` that use the Rails time zone, `Time.now` and `DateTime.now`, ruby classes, use the system's time zone by default.

Comment: So is the convention to always use `Time.zone.now` or `DateTime.current` in Rails code?